# ASPX server code is being created in .aspx file

Tags: c#, asp.net

just moment ago I discovered strange behaviour of my visual studio environment. I'm using ASP.net web application. When the webform is added, and i'm trying to place button on webform, instead of declaring button_Click event in code-behind file (WebForm.aspx.cs) this declaration is placed in aspx.file as follows:

```
<script runat="server">

protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Earlier everything worked correctly. What am i missing?

Comment: Your ASPX is probably missing the `CodeBehind` declerative in it's header

Comment: `<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="WebForm1" Codebehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" %>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for help. unfortunately I don't know the actual reason, but my problem was solved by deleting my web application from solution and then adding this application again.

Answer (score 0):

During new page add operation check the checkbox saying "**Place code in seperate file**".

[image]

Comment: Well it works with new form, but what would i do with all previous? and even hour ago everything worked well. I didn't changed any settings.

Comment: @seeker: Did you mean that the once you added with separate code file now been merged??

Comment: @huMptyduMpty by default if I create webform, i've two files: aspx and aspx.cs. Now these file exists, but new declarations are added to aspx file

Comment: @seeker if your project contains 2 files for each form i.e aspx and aspx.cs, then its a website not a webproject, Webprojects contains one extra file designer.cs. Is this problem is of only one form or all the forms in your website have this behavior, I guess you should try to open your project with open -> website that may solve the issue give it a try.

Comment: @yogi I have .designer.cs file and therefore this is webproject. And the problem now is for all existing forms.